# how do i mimic the result of color ramp in map range? also tips regarding map range on how to use it easily

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

I have been using the node tree in the image to have a Bezier curve displacing the geometry on a plane. I would like to know how to mimic the results of the color ramp in the map range?

Also the position and offset input of set position nodes are giving various results so what's the math behind it?'

[image: GN graph]

this is the result I get while using a color ramp and I need to replicate this in map range[image]

Comment: About the *Set Position* node input sockets: your graph is producing different results because the *Offset* is added to the vertices position, whereas you are subtracting it from the vertices position to compute the new position.

Comment: @StefLAncien so if I remove the position node from the math node I can get the same value while connecting into the offset input as it will not add the position into itself

Comment: The question about map range is not clear to me. Have you tried to map range the distance? What do you obtain that is not what you want?

Comment: @lemon rather than using color ramp to invert the values i want to use map range

Comment: StefLAncien has showed it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

#### 1st attempt

An *Attribute Statistics* node is returning the min and max of a field that can be plugged to a *Map Range* node to linearly bring values between 0 and 1, used afterwards as the *Fac* parameter of the *Color Ramp* node:

[image: GN Graph/]

**Resources:** [image]

#### 2nd attempt

[image: GN graph with map range]

#### 3rd attempt

[image: GN graph with negative displacement]

#### 4th attempt

[image: GN graph with negative map range]

Comment: this is not the result I want to get . I have added the result I need to get.